# Unwanted motion in Plotly camera (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, animation, camera, plotly, frame

I'm plotting the position of an Earth and two antennas with Plotly in Python. Despite my best attempts to keep the camera and viewpoint unchanging, the camera seems to change its position to accomodate for the scene components, despite setting parameters such that this *will not* happen. Here are my settings for the camera...

```
up_dir  = [0,0,1]
cntr_pt = [0,0,0]
eye_pos = [1.5,-0.5,0]

# Parse input parameters
ux,uy,uz = [i for i in up_dir]
cx,cy,cz = [i for i in cntr_pt]
ex,ey,ez = [i for i in eye_pos]

# Set camera angle
camera = dict(
    up=dict(x=ux, y=uy, z=uz),
    center=dict(x=cx, y=cy, z=cz),
    eye=dict(x=ex, y=ey, z=ez)
)
```

and the layout...

```
titlecolor = 'white'
bgcolor = 'black'

# Remove axes from objects in the scene
noaxis = dict(showbackground=False, showgrid=False, showline=False, 
              showticklabels=False, ticks='', title='', zeroline=False)

# Define imagery layout, colors, fonts, ...
layout = go.Layout(autosize=False,
                   titlefont = dict(family='Courier New', color=titlecolor),
                   showlegend = False,                       
                   scene = dict(xaxis=noaxis, yaxis=noaxis, zaxis=noaxis),
                   paper_bgcolor = bgcolor,
                   plot_bgcolor = bgcolor,)
```

Then I am implementing each of these in my code as follows:

```
# ----- CREATE SCENE -----
# Add Earth 
fig = go.Figure(data=topo_earth,layout=layout)

# Add satellite / solar panels 
fig.add_trace(sbtrace)
if spanl is not None: fig.add_trace(sptrace)

# Define / add satellite antenna radiation 
S_rad_trace = go.Mesh3d(x=S_verts[0], y=S_verts[1], z=S_verts[2],
                        i=S_faces[0], j=S_faces[1], k=S_faces[2],
                        opacity=0.5,
                        colorscale='magma_r')
fig.add_trace(S_rad_trace)

# Define / add ground antenna radiation
T_rad_trace = go.Mesh3d(x=T_verts[0], y=T_verts[1], z=T_verts[2],
                        i=T_faces[0], j=T_faces[1], k=T_faces[2],
                        opacity=0.5,
                        colorscale='magma_r')
fig.add_trace(T_rad_trace)

# Apply camera settings
fig.update_layout(scene_camera=camera)

# Write out figure
fig.write_image(outpath)
```

What parameter am I missing or misdefining that causes my animation to look like the following?

[image]

Comment: The scene `camera` config is not used from what I see, you should provide that in the layout if I'm not wrong. Apart from that, as a big part of the code is missing, it's not possible to reproduce and check what's going on, you would have better chance of getting an answer by providing a mwe.

Comment: @EricLavault You're correct, I forgot to add the `camera` implementation -- I've just added that. Given the complexity of what's involved in the simulation, an MWE is difficult, but I'll try to build one soon.